# How to create product lists that use h1, h2 and h3 tags without keyword stuffing

Tags: seo, keywords, keyword-stuffing

We re-manufacture and sell industrial diesel engines such as CAT Engines, Cummins, Detroit and a few others.

Would creating an inventory page with a list of our different engines, each containing make and model information, using h3 tags, be considered keyword stuffing?

We need to have the make and model for each listing so that the viewers know exactly what they are looking at and can make the right choice for their application, but at the same time, that means we will have a bunch of h3 tags with the word Caterpillar engine in it, or Cummins, etc.

We can create h2 categories for the makes themselves, I guess, and then h3 tags for each model(omitting the make since it falls under the make h2 category and should be obvious), but I'd really like to be able to put the make in every time so people know for sure what they are buying. Would that be considered keyword stuffing or can engines determine that we are simply creating a list and describing each product accurately?

Comment: I almost deleted this question as spam. Please consider how you write your questions in the future to avoid this possibility.

Comment: Your scenario is a bit unclear. For example, are you taking about a page that simply lists products? Do you have some sort of product drill-down? Can you tell us more about how this fits into the sites general organization so that we can better assist you? It sounds like, from this reading, that all of your products by category *engine* are listed on a single page. Is that right? Otherwise, I am not sure how to answer this question.

Comment: I tend to stick (as much as commen sense allows) to 1*H1, 2*H2, 3*H3. Not 100% accurate, but if you have 100 products on a page, it's not a H2.

Answer (score 1):

If you are providing information in <h1>, <h2> and <h3> to specify what your content is all about, then you are not practicing keyword stuffing. Search engines appreciate this information and it helps them index your content properly.

If you are intentionally adding keywords in your content, knowing that there are already enough to specify/identify the content of your pages, and for the sole purpose of attracting traffic related to those keywords, then that is keyword stuffing.

Answer (score 1):

What i can understand from your question is : there are N engines with M1 makes and M2 models.

What you are currently doing is **converging a set of huge keywords on a single page** which are essentially a combination of M1*M2 ~ N keywords.

Though this approach is fine if your data set is small, but if number of keywords increase then this page will lose authority for any one keyword and this is targeting lot of things rather than targeting few.

So even if you add h1,h2,h3 tags you can't fool crawlers to target your page for these keywords as someone else might be targeting them well individually or in a group.

There can be multiple solutions to handle this use case, but i would like to highlight one :

Create multiple pages for this use-case.
i.e. one per product (product page)
one per make (listing page type make)
one per model (listing page type model)

Now you can add related keywords on this page (use H1 for a better targeting of the required keyword)

Add some descriptions about the keyword/thing being discussed. Rest of the question can  now be answered as best seo practices for a e-commerce site.

Above is just a suggestion if that suits your implementation and requirement.